# How to put transparent image on camera view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, camera

I'm developing an application that captures live video for performing OCR on images.

I would like to put semi-transparent image on front of the camera view to direct the user how to put the image. like other scan applications do...

Any idea??

Thanks.

Comment: what do you use to present the live video feed?

Answer (score 2):

Just add another view

```
+ view
   + videoPreview + preview Layer
   + overlay view
```

Code might look something like this:

```
videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
[self.videoPreview.layer addSublayer:videoPreviewLayer];
[self.view addSubview:videoPreview];
[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

Edit: cleaned up formatting a tad.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work for me, eventually I switched between the 2 views and now it works!

THANKS!